# Parser to read multiple xml file with same XSD and XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation

I  want to read the data from multiple XML files based on the XSD  document and the structure of one XML file will not be the same as to another but will follow the xsd schema. Also, the xmls are nested xmls.Can someone help me with it so that I can use the already created utility and add the attributes to it? I need a XML parser which parses each xml file(They are different) based on the xsd schema and returns me a list of the map so that the data can be matched with the DB data.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        try {

            File file = new File("SalesPoslog20200225104558676.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    int organizationID;
    int retailStoreID;
    int workstationID;
    int tillID;
    int sequenceNumber;

    public int organizationID() {
        return organizationID;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void RetailStoreID(int  retailStoreID) {
        this.retailStoreID = retailStoreID;
    }

    public int workstationID() {
        return workstationID;
    }



    @XmlAttribute
    public void RetailStoreId(int RetailStoreId) {
        this.retailStoreID = retailStoreID;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is confusing to me.  You’re using JAXB, which already enforces a particular XML structure, so why do you care about a schema?  Why do you need a JSON parser, when JSON has nothing to do with XML?

Comment: @VGR jaxb I want to get the data from the parser.

Comment: Just as JAXBContext has a `createMarshaller` method, it also has a [createUnmarshaller](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#createUnmarshaller--) method.  The javadoc should tell you everything you need to know.